# Android app automation for Audio input/output

Tags: java, android, adb, webrtc

Trying to automate Google Now/ Rosetta Stone or some other Audio related app

1. Uploading Input audio files which transfers to the remote node
2. On the Remote Node the audio input files are played such that the Android devices connected to node listens the audio (PC <--> Aux Cable wire <--> Android Device )
3. Android App responds back to the Audio input files with expected audio output
4. Expected Output is validated on the remote node

Can somebody suggest me, is that possible to play/listen the audio of the connected android device WITHOUT AUX CABLE WIRE ?